# How to invoke multiple calls in pre/postinstall scripts in package.json

Tags: json, node.js

I want to run a couple different scripts during preinstall, and a few postinstall, but the examples on npm where they split the calls using semi-colons doesn't work, and ends up throwing an error.  Was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "composer install; php artisan key:generate; grunt build:app",
    "install": "bower install",
    "postinstall": "bin\\post_install.sh git@bitbucket.project/project.git"
  },
```

I wanted to have "bower install" in postinstall, but didn't work so since install is essentially the same I put it there, now that I want a couple preinstall calls invoked I don't have the same solution available since only one option.  I didn't want to split them all out in bash scripts for each if possible.

Comment: How about using `&&` instead of `;`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Also tried this as an array.

Comment: `scripts` are just shell scripts with additional `PATH` to `node_modules/.bin`. Do your scripts work without npm?

Comment: Also, you'll get better answers if you show the errors you got.

Comment: Your right @ShuheiKagawa && works, it didn't like version number in my package.json (for some reason) had 0.1 and changed it 0.1.0, once that was done no problems.  Thanks for the help, if you drop this as the answer I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1):

Separate commands using '&&' like this:

```
"preinstall": "composer install && php artisan key:generate && grunt build:app"
```